# quickpay amout: is too large

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7

after updating magento 1.7 with security patches I have started to get following error when try to capture payment from QuickPay

```
Not able to capture your payment online, due to this error: Failure to capture: 
{"message":"Validation error","errors":{"amount":["is too large"]},"error_code":null}
```

Anyone know how to this this error ?